# How to use svg polygons custom attributes (data-*) to style these same polygons?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm very new to programming and coding. I'm using a .svg file generated by Adobe Illustrator to make an interactive map with d3.js.

This SVG is organized with g's with polygon's inside which have their own id's. I also added custom data do each polygon in the SVG (data-price="number"):

```
<g id="price-range">
    <polygon id="name" data-price="price number" points="..."/>
    <polygon id="name2" data-price="price2 number" points="..."/>
    // and so on
</g>
```

I would like to use those custom data attributes as data to generate different style outputs for each of these polygon's. This is my code so far (it's not working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map-block {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1000px;
            align-content: center;
            margin: auto; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map-block">    
        <svg id="mapa-usados-sp" width="100%"></svg>
    </div>

    <script>
        var svg = null;
        var mapa = null;

        d3.xml("sp.svg", function(error, xml) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var domSVG = document.getElementById('mapa-usados-sp');
        domSVG.appendChild(xml.documentElement.getElementById('mapa'));  

        svg = d3.select(domSVG);
        mapa = svg.select('#mapa');

        var xmlSVG = d3.select(xml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]);
        svg.attr('viewBox', xmlSVG.attr('viewBox'));

        var bg = mapa.selectAll("g#contexto");  
            bg.style("fill", "#e9e9e9");    

        var shapes = mapa.select("g#zones").selectAll("polygon");
        var price = shapes.(xml.documentElement.getAttribute('data-
          price'));
        shapes.style("fill", function(price) {
                if (price = 0) { return "#323232";}
                if (price <= 1700 && price > 0 ) {return "#2169dd";}
                if (price > 1700 && d <= 2500) {return "#6921dd";}
        });                 
    });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I chose not to style each shape refering to it's id or class because I would really like to use the custom-data attributes in the .svg file to generate visual outputs.

In the end this will be a very dynamic piece. I'm going to add interactions and event listeners, so this is why I'm very interested in finding out how to extract data from .svg attributes and use it to style the shapes that contain these attributes.

I hope I have made my point corretly.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: Your question's *title* was a bit misleading: it was asking about passing the data attributes to the D3 `data()` function. However, in the question itself there is no `data` function, and besides that you have no "enter" selection. Thus, I removed the reference to D3 `data()` in the title.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it's true, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the "data" attribute of each polygon is using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element, either in HTML or in the DOM.

In your case, where `this` is the current DOM element:

```
this.dataset.price
```

Pay attention that this will return a string, you may want to coerce it to a number.

Here is the demo, using the value of `data-price` to fill the polygons:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var shapes = svg.selectAll("polygon");

shapes.each(function() {
  var thisPrice = +this.dataset.price;
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", thisPrice === 0 ? "#323232" : 
  thisPrice > 1700 ? "#6921dd" : "#2169dd")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <polygon id="name1" data-price="0" points="30,10 10,50 50,50" />
  <polygon id="name2" data-price="1000" points="80,10 60,50 100,50" />
  <polygon id="name3" data-price="2000" points="130,10 110,50 150,50" />
</svg>
```

PS: It's not clear what's the colour if the value is above 2500.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo, your answer solved my question at its core and even thaught me a new powerful tool that is the d3.js's "selection.each" call. Thanks for the quick reply and I apologize for the delay on my answer!